# Homomorphisms of R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, group-homomorphism

I know that for Groups $G$, $G'$ and $G''$, if $f_1: G \rightarrow G'$ and $f_2: G \rightarrow G''$ are homomorphisms  of groups, then the function $f :G \rightarrow G' \times G''$ defined by $f(g) = (f_1(g),f_2(g))$ is a homomorphism of groups.

My question is does this extend to $R$-modules, where $R$ is a commutative ring. In other words, for $R$- Modules $M$, $M'$ and $M''$, if $f_1: M \rightarrow M'$ and $f_2: M \rightarrow M''$ are homomorphisms  of $R$ -Modules , then the function $f: M \rightarrow M' \oplus M''$ defined by $f(m) = (f_1(m),f_2(m))$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules.

I feel like this should be the case, since the $M$'s are abelian groups.

Comment: It is not because modules are abelian groups. While necessary, this is not sufficient. This is true, because... it is true. This is a simple thing to check, so what have you tried?

Comment: I see. I have tried doing a direct proof. I think i may have made a mistake showing that $f$ is $R$-linear.

Comment: Is $f$ $R$-linear since $ r f(m) = r(f_1(m),f_2(m)) = (rf_1(m), rf_2(m)) = (f_1(rm) , f_2(rm)) = f(rm)$ for all $r \in R$.?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This together with the fact that it is a homomorphism of underlying abelian groups proves it.